# Jquery attr('src') undefined in IE 8 (works in FF)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This has gotten so far,that I will sum up what we found out:

- Inside the event handler the attribute src cannot be read in IE8 (FF works fine), neither with jQuery nor with usual javascript
- The only way to get the data was to get it outside the handler, write it to an array and read it afterwards from the inside of the handler
- But there was still no possibility to write to src (neither jQuery nor javascript worked - only for IE 8)
- I've got it working by writing the img elemts themselves to the document, but the reason behind this problem is no solved

The snippet we have is used twice.

**The old code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//...
//view entry
jQuery('.blogentry').live('click',function(){
    // Get contents
    blogtext = jQuery(this).children('.blogtext').html();
    blogauthor = jQuery(this).children('.onlyblogauthor').html();
    blogtitle = jQuery(this).children('.blogtitle').html();
    profileimage = jQuery(this).children('.profileimage').html();
    imgleft = jQuery(this).children('.Image_left').attr('src');
    imgcenter = jQuery(this).children('.Image_center').attr('src');
    imgright = jQuery(this).children('.Image_right').attr('src');

    // Write contents
    jQuery('#bild_left').attr('src', imgleft);
    jQuery('#bild_center').attr('src', imgcenter);
    jQuery('#bild_right').attr('src', imgright);
    jQuery('.person').attr('src', profileimage);
    jQuery('#g_fb_name').html(blogauthor);
    jQuery('#g_titel').html(blogtitle);
    jQuery('#g_text').html(blogtext);
    //...
});
//...
// Change entry
jQuery('.blogentry').each(function(){
    entryindex = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    if (entry == entryindex)
    {
        // The following works fine (so 'children' works fine):
        blogtext = jQuery(this).children('.blogtext').html();
        blogauthor = jQuery(this).children('.onlyblogauthor').html();
        blogtitle = jQuery(this).children('.blogtitle').html();
        profileimage = jQuery(this).children('.profileimage').html();

        // This does not work - only in IE 8, works in Firefox
        imgleft = jQuery(this).children('.Image_left').attr('src');
        imgcenter = jQuery(this).children('.Image_center').attr('src');
        imgright = jQuery(this).children('.Image_right').attr('src');

        //alert: 'undefined'
        alert(jQuery(this).children('.Image_center').attr('src'));

        //...
    }
}
//...
});
</script>
```

**The new code**

Please see my own posted answer for the new code.

**UPDATE:**

This does **not** work if called inside of the click event!!!

```
jQuery('.Image_left').each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this).attr('src'));
});
```

SOLUTION TO GET THE IMAGE DATA:

```
relcounter = 1;
imgleft_array = new Array();
jQuery('.Image_left').each(function(){
imgleft_array[relcounter] = jQuery(this).attr('src');
relcounter++;
});
relcounter = 1;
imgcenter_array = new Array();
jQuery('.Image_center').each(function(){
imgcenter_array[relcounter] = jQuery(this).attr('src');
relcounter++;
});
relcounter = 1;
imgright_array = new Array();
jQuery('.Image_right').each(function(){
imgright_array[relcounter] = jQuery(this).attr('src');
relcounter++;
});

//... inside the eventhandler (entryindex = 'rel' of blogentry):
imgleft = imgleft_array[entryindex];
imgcenter = imgcenter_array[entryindex];
imgright = imgright_array[entryindex];
```

This works because it is not called inside the event handler and the sources are saved beforehand

BUT! **I still cannot write the data, which is my aim:**

```
jQuery('#bild_left').attr('src', imgleft);
jQuery('#bild_center').attr('src', imgcenter);
jQuery('#bild_right').attr('src', imgright);
```

UPDATE!!!

This is just crazy, I tried to write the data via usual javascript. This also works in FF, but no in IE8. Here really is some serious problem witt the attribute src:

```
document.getElementById('bild_left').src = imgleft;
document.getElementById('bild_center').src = imgcenter;
document.getElementById('bild_right').src = imgright;

alert(document.getElementById('bild_left').src);
```

This works in FF, but not in IE8, the attribute src remains undefined after writing! This seems to be not a jQuery problem at all!

Comment: Can you provide the relevant html as well?

Comment: instead of "alert(...)" try to use "console.log(...)", as well as "developper tools" of ie/ff(firebug)/chrome.

you will be able to inspect the element in details.

"[Object object]" can mean that an element is returned by the jquery function... or an error object. So console is handy here.

Comment: I have provided the html code. Well I have proved so far, that a valid object is returned. console.log() does throw an error, does this only work with a certain plugin?

Comment: I think you should show us the whole click function. Because your snippets are OK themself.

Comment: I added the code and showed both handlers. Its used twice but it acts the same in both cases... I've got it working now by writing the img elemts with html(). Thnak you so much. I guess this will stay a riddle ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has gotten so far,that I will sum up what we found out:

- Inside the event handler the attribute src cannot be read in IE8 (FF works fine), neither with jQuery nor with usual javascript
- The only way to get the data was to get it outside the handler, write it to an array and read it afterwards from the inside of the handler
- But there was still no possibility to write to src (neither jQuery nor javascript worked - only for IE 8)
- I've got it working by writing the img elemts themselves to the document, but the reason behind this problem is no solved

**The new code**

```
relcounter = 1;
imgleft_array = new Array();
jQuery('.Image_left').each(function(){
    imgleft_array[relcounter] = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    relcounter++;
});
relcounter = 1;
imgcenter_array = new Array();
jQuery('.Image_center').each(function(){
    imgcenter_array[relcounter] = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    relcounter++;
});
relcounter = 1;
imgright_array = new Array();
jQuery('.Image_right').each(function(){
    imgright_array[relcounter] = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    relcounter++;
});

//view entry
jQuery('.blogentry').live('click',function(){
    // Get contents
    entryindex = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    blogtext = jQuery(this).children('.blogtext').html();
    blogauthor = jQuery(this).children('.onlyblogauthor').html();
    blogtitle = jQuery(this).children('.blogtitle').html();
    profileimage = jQuery(this).children('.profileimage').html();
    imgleft = imgleft_array[entryindex];
    imgcenter = imgcenter_array[entryindex];
    imgright = imgright_array[entryindex];

    // Write contents
    jQuery('#entryimages').html('');
    jQuery('#entryimages').html('<img class="rotate" width="132" height="138" id="bild_left" src="'+imgleft+'" /><img class="rotateright" width="154" height="162" id="bild_center" src="'+imgcenter+'" /><img class="rotate" width="132" height="138" id="bild_right" src="'+imgright+'" />');

    jQuery('.person').attr('src', profileimage);
    jQuery('#g_fb_name').html(blogauthor);
    jQuery('#g_titel').html(blogtitle);
    jQuery('#g_text').html(blogtext);

});
```

So I am just not using .attr('src') in the event handler....

Answer (score 2):

`children` looks for immediate child elements only where as `find` looks for all the elements within it until its last child element down the dom tree. If you are saying `find` is working that means the element you are looking is not its immediate children.

Try to alert this `jQuery(this).children('#Image_center').length` see what you get.

FYI. Even when any element is not found jQuery will return an emtpy object it will never be null. So alert an emtpy object will always give you `[object Object]`. You should alwasy check for the `length` property of the jQuery object.

Try this

`alert(jQuery(this).find('#Image_center').length);`//To check whether element is found or not.

Comment: He's not saying that `find` is working and `children` isn't.  I think the `find` example was just supposed to show that the element did exist, while the 2nd half of your answer points out why that was flawed.  He was able to get the `class` and `id` so he appears to be getting the element.

Comment: I tried to explain him the difference between `find` and `children` in the first half of my answer and in the second half how to check if the element exists or not.

Comment: Right, I agree with everything you said, it just doesn't solve his problem.  He gets the element (since he can get the `class` and `id`), just not its `src`.

Comment: Well thanks for the explanation, I was not aware of the fact that javascript always returns an object, but as kingjiv said the object is found as I can read the class and id. Anyways I tried 'alert(jQuery(this).find('#Image_center').length);' and it returned 1. So yes the object is found. It seems to be a problem with 'src'. Also I could not get the attribute 'alt'.

Comment: Sorry! I was wrong I am getting the attribute 'alt' but only by using find()!!! But 'src' remains undefined. By using children 'alt' is as well undefined. I do not really understand why....

Comment: Can you tell use where(in which event handler) are you executing this code? I need to need what `this` is pointing to in this code. That way it will be very easy to say whether to use `children` or `find`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: Added the event handler. In my opinion children is correct, because blogentry is the direct parent. attr('rel') on top of the event handler works fine in IE 8

Comment: I changed the ids from the images to classes (id was wrong at this point), but that was not the solution to my problem.
But! I found out that the following returns the src:

    alert(jQuery('.blogentry .Image_left').attr('src'));

My problem, it seems it works not with jQuery(this) but I need this connection to the defined element.

Comment: This does not work as well:

jQuery('.Image_left').each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this).attr('src'));
});

Answer (score 2):

Bing Bang Boom,

```
imgright = jQuery(".Image_right",this).attr('src');
```

Comment: Wow, that seemed so promising, but still undefined :-( Thank you, didnt know of this notation

Comment: This does not work as well:

jQuery('.Image_left').each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this).attr('src'));
});

Answer (score 1):

And why don't you easily use one working?

```
alert(jQuery(this).children('#Image_center').attr('src'));
```

change children to find

```
alert(jQuery(this).find('#Image_center').attr('src'));
```

It is probably the easiest solution, and when it work, why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood! The object is returned either way with children and find. But the attr('src') stays empty for both variations - I have alread triedl - and only in IE 8!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not in the **attr('src')** but in something else. The following snippet works in IE8:

```
    <img id="xxx" src="yrdd">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        alert($('#xxx').attr('src'));

    </script>
```

But if you for example change the the **text/javascript** to **application/javascript** - this code will work in FF but will not work in IE8

Comment: Still not my problem :-/ I had already the type "text/javascript", but thanks! (I will add that in my post)

Comment: I changed the ids from the images to classes (id was wrong at this point), but that was not the solution to my problem.
But! I found out that the following returns the src:

    alert(jQuery('.blogentry .Image_left').attr('src'));

My problem, it seems it works not with jQuery(this) but I need this connection to the defined element.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a delay:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function () {

    jQuery('.blogentry').each(function(){
      // your code...
    });

  }, 100); // if doesn't work, try to set a higher value

});
```

UPDATE

Hope, this code will work.

```
$('.blogentry img').each(function(){
  alert( $(this).attr('src') );
});
```

UPDATE

I'm not sure, but maybe IE can't read classes with uppercase first letter...
Try to change ".Image_center" to ".image_center"

UPDATE

Check your code again. You definitely have some error. Try this jsfiddle in IE8, attr('src') is showed correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/qzFU8/

Comment: I set the the value up until 5000, but still no success. But! I found out that the following returns the src (I have changed the ids to classes, check my updated question):

alert(jQuery('.blogentry .Image_left').attr('src'));

My problem, it seems it works not with jQuery(this) but I need this connection to the defined element.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But this works only called outside the event handler. View the end of my question I am getting the data now by saving it to an array, but i still can't write it... any idea, doesnt matter if its a nice an clean way anymore :-/

Comment: Had no effect, capital letters do not matter... but I already assumed that, because I looped through the image by their class name (check my post at the top).

Comment: Please check my post again. I wrote the data using normal javascript, it works in FF, but it does not work in IE8! This is not a jQuery problem, with javascript it does not work as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgReload").click(function () {
        $('#<%=imgCaptcha.ClientID %>').removeAttr("src");
        $('#<%=imgCaptcha.ClientID %>').attr("src", "Captcha.ashx");
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting idea, I did not try removing the attribute beforehand, but I am not working anymore on the regarding project, so I cannot test, if this is a solution to the problem. Note: In other projects I changed the src attribute without problems, even in IE8 - so this is are rather specific circumstances with the cause still unknown. But maybe your answer will help.